# WAV file from user microphone vs. WAV file from file: Some difference is causing bugs, but what are these different?

Tags: javascript, django, audio, amazon-s3

Right now I have two methods of sending a WAV file to the server. A user can directly upload said file, or make a recording on their microphone. Once the files are sent, they are processed in nigh the same way. The file is sent to S3, and can later be played by clicking on some link (which plays the file via `audio = new Audio('https://S3.url'); audio.play()`

When dealing with a file from the microphone:

- `audio.play()` seems to work. Everything in the `audio` object is identical (except for the URL itself), but the sound won't actually play through the speakers. On the other hand, for an uploaded file, the sound plays through the speakers.
- When I visit the URLs directly—both of them open up the sound-player (in Chrome) or prompt a download for a WAV file (in Firefox). The sound-player appropriately plays *both* sounds, and the downloaded WAV files each contain their respective sound, which other programs can play
- If I actually *download* the file with sound from the user's microphone instead of sending it directly to the server, then manually upload the WAV file, everything works as it should (as it would with any other uploaded WAV file).
- In any scenario where the microphone-sound is uploaded somewhere, then downloaded, it is downloaded as a WAV file and plays accordingly. Anything which uses the re-uploaded WAV file works as intended.

---

Here's how I'm getting the sound from the user's microphone. First, I use [WebAudioTrack](https://github.com/danielstorey/WebAudioTrack) to place a record button on my webpage. Once the user stops their recording, they hit the submit button which runs:

```
saveRecButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    save_recording(audioTrack.audioData.getChannelData(0))
});
```

Here, `audioTrack.audioData` is an [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) containing the recorded sound. `getChannelData(0)` is a `Float32Array` representing the sound. I send this array to the server (Django) via AJAX:

```
function save_recording(channelData){
    var uploadFormData = new FormData();
    uploadFormData.append('data', $('#some_field').val());
    ...
    uploadFormData.append('audio', channelData);

    $.ajax({
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': '/soundtests/save_recording/',
        'data': uploadFormData,
        'cache': false,
        'contentType': false,
        'processData': false,
        success: function(dataReturned) { 
            if (dataReturned != "success") {
               [- Do Some Stuff -]
            }
    });
}
```

Then, using [wavio](https://pypi.org/project/wavio/), a WAV file is written from an array:

```
import wavio
import tempfile
from numpy import array
def save_recording(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        form = SoundForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as sound_recording:
                sound_array_string = request.POST.get('audio')
                sound_array = array([float(x) for x in sound_array_string.split(',')])
                wavio.write(sound_recording, sound_array, 48000, sampwidth=4)
                sound_recording.seek(0)
                s3_bucket.put_object(Key=some_key, Body=sound_recording, ContentType='audio/x-wav')
            return HttpResponse('success')
```

Then, when the sound needs to be listened to:

In Python:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='key', aws_secret_access_key='s_key')
bucket = self.session.resource('s3').Bucket(name='bucket_name')
url = session.client('s3').generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket':bucket.name, Key:'appropriate_sound_key'})
```

Then, in JavaScript:

```
audio = new Audio('url_given_by_above_python')
audio.play()
```

The audio plays well if I upload a file, but doesn't play at all if I use the user's microphone. Is there something about WAV files I might be missing that's done when I upload the microphone sound to S3, then re-download it? I have *no* clue where to go next; everything between the two files seems identical. Here's a dump of two `Audio` objects with URLs from the user's mic. and another created from a file manually uploaded *that was re-downloaded from that exact user-mic. file* look exactly the same (except for the URL, which, upon visiting or downloading, plays both sounds).

There's got to be some difference here, but I have no idea what it is, and have been struggling with this for a few days now. :(

Comment: What does the `fmt ` chunk of each file contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sound file you're creating is 32-bit PCM, which is an arguably non-standard audio codec. Chrome supports it ([source](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video)) but Firefox does not ([source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox), [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=524109)).

Encode it as 16-bit PCM and it'll be universally acceptable.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, [this](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio/blob/3c57b855fcc8be97254ec043284e46413c404055/wavio.py#L240) is the parameter in question.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm assuming this means change `sampwidth` from `4` to `2`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yessir! (lines 237 - 241 of wavio's [source](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio/blob/master/wavio.py))